# css responsive design. 2 columns fixed width. Middle div dynamic width. At certain window width one column is at new line

Tags: css

Here example http://jsfiddle.net/oop4kdn6/33/

```
<div style="float:left;" id="leftsidebar1" >Left sidebar</div>
<div style="float:left;" id="maincontent1" >Main content</div>    
<div style="float:left;" id="rightsidebar1">Right sidebar</div>
```

And css which i testing and where see problem

```
@media screen and (min-width: 641px) and (max-width: 900px) {
#maincontent1{ min-width: 241px; max-width: 500px }
#leftsidebar1, #rightsidebar1{width:200px;}    
}
```

So. If window width is at least 641px and not more than 900px, then width of both sidebars is 200px. And width of middle column (div `#maincontent1`) i expect actual window width, minus 400px (200 x 2).

Problem is if window width is from 641px until 658px, then `#rightsidebar1` is at new line. If more than 658px, then all divs in one line.

As i understand to avoid the problem, i must set less `min-width` for #maincontent1. But do not understand why. For example if window width 650px. It must be enough to show all columns in one line. Because 200+200+241=641.

Why the `#rightsidebar1` is at new line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
@media screen and (min-width: 641px) and (max-width: 900px) 
{

  *
  {     
      margin:0px;
  }
  #maincontent1{ min-width: 241px; max-width: 500px }
  #leftsidebar1, #rightsidebar1{width:200px;}    
}
```

by default page has some margin.
its good practice to always use

```
*{margin:0px}
```

to remove default margin

Comment: Thanks! If width is 641px or 642px, right sidebar is in new line. As understand it is because container div has line with border 1px (1px from both sides). Seems now question is clear. http://jsfiddle.net/oop4kdn6/39/

Comment: Tested again with longer text in one column http://jsfiddle.net/oop4kdn6/43/ and right sidebar is in new line. window width : 729, maincontent1 width : 500 and each sidebar 200. To avoid right sidebar is in new line must set fixed maincontent1 width http://jsfiddle.net/oop4kdn6/44/. Or other solution? At the moment my conclusion is that with css @media screen too many problems. Seems better to use jquery?

Comment: i don't understand your question....at window size 729px both sidebar 200px so width left for maincontent1 div is 729px-400px=329px ,so if the content is bigger than 329px and less then 500px(max-width for maincontent1 div) then right sidebar will definitely go down...........and css media query is very easy and without problems once you understand it

Comment: I expected main content to be 329px. I expected 729 (window width)-400(width of both sidebars). I set minimum width for main content `min-width: 241px;` and expected that main content would use minimum width or more. But it uses maximum width. Found one solution for css to set width in percentages. But for certain range may need to set different percentages. Yes, read that need to use css and not jquery. So must understand how css works.

Comment: Created percentage based on following rules: 1) container max-width:990px; 2) min-width of sidebars 200px, max 215px; 3) min width of middle column:360px. As result 9 variants of percentages. Here uploaded the file http://files.fm/u/otxyylg